# Laravel getPrefix - slash prepended on local but not production

Tags: laravel

I have a check in my code that doesn't work in production mode.

In local mode, the code returns the prefix of a route with a forward slash prepended but in production, it doesn't.

My route is defined without a forward slash in the prefix.

Any ideas why this would be returning different results?

```
Route::current()->getPrefix() == '/xxx'

Route::name('business.')
    ->prefix('business')
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Livewire\Marketing\Business\Index')->name('index');
    });
```

Comment: You do define the `prefix` in the actions part of a defined route right? Where and how are you doing this? As in, how does your `Route::prefix` look like.

Comment: @dbf Have updated the question with the route.

Comment: Where is this check defined? Do you know the value of `Route::current()->getPrefix()` in production when it should be working? Do you have route caching on production?